# Django dynamically filter list in template

Tags: django, dynamic, filtering

I have a page which lists all of the `athletes` that a certain `coach` has.  Coaches, however, can have multiple teams and I am trying to allow them to select a team from a dropdown at the top of the page and dynamically filter the list of athletes to only show those on the selected team.

My template:

```
<table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Team</h3></td>
                <td><h3>First Name</h3></td>
                <td><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
                <td><h3>Email</h3></td>
            </tr>
            {% for athlete in athletes %}
                {% if not athlete.coach_ind %}
                <tr><td>
                        {% for team in athlete.team.all %}
                            {{ team.school }} {{ team.mascot }} {{ team.sport }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>

                    <td>{{ athlete.user.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ athlete.user.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ athlete.user.email }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

My view:

```
teams_list = request.user.profile.team.all()
athletes = UserProfile.objects.filter(team__in=teams_list).order_by('team','user__last_name')
```

I am able to successfully get the correct list of all athletes and their information, I'm just not sure how to create a dynamic filter to show only by team.

Comment: You need to write an ajax call to pull the data from your server and update the list. There's nothing django template can do naturally.

Comment: What would be the process to go about doing this?

Comment: I did some googling and here's an example: http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/, not sure if make sense to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use django-filter for it https://github.com/alex/django-filter.

Example from documentation:

**Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
```

**Filter**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['manufacturer']
```

**View**

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```

**Template**

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% for obj in filter %}
        {{ obj.name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE Explain me this line {{ filter.form.as_p }} {% for obj in filter %}
        {{ obj.name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Another app to those for this type of "chained" selection is selectable (http://django-selectable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#chained-selection). You have to put some additional javascript to the template, though.